# How to sanitize raw SQL in a Ruby script

Tags: ruby, sequel

I'm trying to write a script that connects with a database using Sequel.

If I have a SQL query like this:

```
record_values = csv_row.to_h.values.join(', ')

sql_query = "INSERT INTO table (#{ COLUMN_NAMES.join(', ') }) VALUES (#{ record_values })"
```

and the array `record_values` is dangerous.

How can I sanitize it?

I tried to sanitize using

```
ActiveRecord.sanitize_sql_array(sql_query)
```

but I kept getting the error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method 'sanitize_sql_array' for ActiveRecord:Module
```

Comment: Since you mention `ActiveRecord` – is this a Rails question?

Comment: @Stefan No it's not a Rails question

Comment: But you use / can use `ActiveRecord`?

Comment: @Stefan I tried to use its sanitization methods but failed. I think they require me to have a connection but I'm using sequel gem to connect to database

Comment: I don't know Sequel, but they have a [Security Guide](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel/blob/master/doc/security.rdoc) containing several examples.

Comment: You are generating a direct SQL statement, but using Sequel? That's wasting a huge amount of capability that Sequel brings to the table, especially when trying to guard against injection attacks. I'd recommend learning to use the gem and its language rather than just use it to connect only. It's not hard to learn, and the documentation is very good, and the author is extremely responsive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know Sequel, but did you try standard [`insert`](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel#inserting-records) method?

```rb
connection = Sequel.connect('...')
table_name = connection.from(:table_name)
# OR
# table_name = DB.from(:table_name)
# table_name = DB[:table_name]
table_name.insert(csv_row.to_h)
```

It's more reliable I believe, because you avoid difference between `COLUMN_NAMES` and `record_values`.